# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header on assets using SvelteKit adapter-node (Vite)

Tags: cors, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I built an app using SvelteKit adapter-node.
And I'd like to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on a script asset which is located in `{project root}/static` directory.

Below are some ways I tried but didn't work.

**Trial#1 Adding `cors` option on `svelte.config.js`**
: It worked in development environment(`npm run dev`) but not in production environment(`npm run build && npm run preview`). There was no point because `cors` option is enabled by default according to https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-cors.

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            postcss: true,
        }),
    ],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        vite: () => ({
            server: {
                fs: {
                    allow: ['./static']
                },
                cors: true
            }
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

**Trial#2 Adding `cors` option on `svelte.config.js`**
: It also worked in development environment but not in production environment. (This solution referred to https://github.com/chaosprint/vite-plugin-cross-origin-isolation)

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            postcss: true,
        }),
    ],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        vite: () => ({
            server: {
                fs: {
                    allow: ['./static']
                },
            },
            plugins: [
                {
                    name: 'configure-response-headers',
                    configureServer: (server) => {
                        server.middlewares.use((incomingMessage, serverReponse, next) => {
                            serverReponse.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                            next();
                        });
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

**Trial#3 Adding response header on `hook.js`**
: It didn't work at all because assets don't go through hook.

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    const response = await resolve(event);
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return response;
}
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: I think you can do it by creating a custom server, i'm not sure. Check the node adapter docs here where it talks about a custom server
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node#custom-server
You can also use polka instead of express

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @unloco, I solved the problem by setting up my own server.

I added `/server.js` file on project root and started with `npm run build && node ./server.js`.

```
// server.js
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

// add a route that lives separately from the SvelteKit app
// Set response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'
app.get('/myscript.js', cors({origin:'*'}));

// let SvelteKit handle everything else, including serving prerendered pages and static assets
app.use(handler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 3000');
});
```